# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre una propiedad y un método en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Mi duda surge al ver en las referencias de Javascript que `length` es considerada una propiedad. ¿Qué hace `length` para que sea considerada una propiedad y no un método? Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si nos basamos en los conceptos de POO (Programación Orientada a Objetos) una propiedad es una característica del objeto mientras que un método es una acción.

El típico ejemplo sería la clase perro en donde el color de pelo es una propiedad mientras que correr sería un método.

Si nos basamos en esta definición esta claro que `length` sería la longitud o sea es una magnitud que describe la instancia, por eso es una propiedad.

Aquí

[Introducción a JavaScript orientado a objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introducci%C3%B3n_a_JavaScript_orientado_a_objetos)

se describe esto mismo que comento

Comment: Gracias Leandro, ya salí de la duda.

Comment: Esto no es cierto. En javascript, en la clase perro, correr es tanto una propiedad como un método. Javascript no tiene clases(eso incluye a ES6 ya que son simplemente sintactic sugar sobre funciones) por lo que la logica tradicional de la POO no aplica aquí. Si correr no fuera una propiedad de la clase perro el valor de `this` cuando ejecutas `perro.correr()` fuera el objeto global y en este caso es la misma instancia de la clase. cc:// @agujex

Comment: @devconcept ok pero no estas llendo a un punto muy fino y particular en la implementacion particular de javascript, entendi que se buscaba conceptos fundamentales de POO en donde se deja entender de forma clara y concreta, digo que se ganas con complicarle el entendimiento de conceptos basicos? Respecto al metodo correr() en realida depende como lo definas, si declaro function correr() { ... } eso es un metodo/funcion. Tampoco creo que era la idea meterse con prototype o IIFE (http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), etc

Comment: La pregunta está etiquetada como javascript, tiene javascript en el título y la forma en que los objetos funcionan en javascript no es la misma que en los demás lenguajes. En lugar de confundir busco aclarar un error de concepto que es muy común en los que buscan aprender el lenguaje. Creo que eso es mejor que venir a darse cuenta del error después de varios años de uso.

Comment: La respuesta de Leandro está buena porque te hace entender rápidamente porque length es una propiedad, pero creo que es importante dejar en claro de que un método puede ser una propiedad y una propiedad un método como dice @devconcept. Gracias.

Comment: No digo que no sea importante tenerlo en cuenta, pero recuerda que esto tambien esta cambiando, ES6 y TypeScript lo estan adaptando para que javascript se aproxime a los conceptos de POO comunes de todos los lenguajes deberian implementar.

Comment: @agujex Por tratar de generalizar el sistema de herencia de javascript y compararlo con los demás lenguajes es que existen preguntas como esta en SO en inglés http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript que te enseñan que no funcionan igual. Ni ES6, ni TypeScript tienen clases "tecnicamente hablando" pues en el primero es azucar sintáctico y el segundo compila a javascript. Son aproximaciones, sólo eso. Lee http://raganwald.com/2014/01/19/prototypes-are-not-classes.html y http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752868/does-javascript-have-classes

Answer (score 7):

Los métodos en cualquier lenguaje son rutinas de código invocables. Esto significa que cuando son referenciadas con un símbolo definido por el lenguaje se ejecuta dicho código. En javascript este símbolo son los parentesis `()` y los métodos se crean usando funciones.

Ejemplo

```js
var fnA = function() {
  return 'resultado fnA'
}

// Imprime el contenido de la funcion (equivalente a fnA.toString())
console.log(fnA);
// Ejecuta el bloque de código de la función e imprime su retorno
console.log(fnA())
```

Las propiedades en javascript son características de todos los objetos excepto `null` y `undefined` que son valores [primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Primitivo) que carecen de su equivalente objeto wrapper.

```
'test' -> primitivo
new String() -> wrapper

123   -> primitivo
new Number() -> wrapper
```

Puedes pensar en ellas como una especie de almacén clave-valor. Dicho valor a su vez puede ser otro objeto o una función ya que las funciones en javascript también son objetos. Son básicamente direcciones de memoria asociadas a un objeto.

[image: Objeto javascript]

```js
var fnA = function() {
  console.log('resultado fnA');
}

var obj2 = {
  prop1: fnA,
  prop2: 'valor2',
  prop3: 'valor3'
};

var obj = {
  prop1: 'valor1',
  prop2: obj2,
  prop3: fnA
}

for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log(prop + ':', obj[prop]);
}

for (var prop in obj2) {
  console.log(prop + ':', obj2[prop]);
}

console.log('obj.prop3 es el mismo objeto que obj2.prop1');

console.log(obj.prop3 === obj2.prop1);
```

En tu caso `length` es una propiedad porque está **asociada a un objeto** determinado y no es un método porque **no es invocable**. Esto es lo que hace la diferencia entre uno y otro tipo. Siguiendo la logica de lo anterior puedes tener lo siguiente:

```
// No es ni un método ni una propiedad
var obj = {};

// Es un método pero no es una propiedad 
var fn = function() {};

var obj = {}
// Es una propiedad pero no es un método
obj.prop = 10;

var obj = {};
// Es tanto una propiedad como un método
obj.prop = function() {};
```

Ten en cuenta que los métodos o funciones cambian el valor de `this` si son invocados como propiedades de un objeto o como funciones regulares.

```js
'use strict';

var fn = function() {
  return this;
}

var obj = {
  prop1: 'valor',
  prop2: fn
}

// undefined en modo estricto
// el valor de window sin modo estricto
console.log(fn());
// el valor del "objeto inmediato" al que hace referencia la propiedad, en este caso obj
console.log(obj.prop2());
// si fuera a.b.c.d() sería el objeto almacenado en c
```

Como nota adicional también los elementos de un [arreglo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) son propiedades de este, al igual mismo nivel que `length`, `toString()`, `filter()`, `map()`, etc. Desde el punto de vista del lenguaje todos son propiedades por igual.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
// se puede acceder a una propiedad usando objeto.propiedad u objeto['propiedad']
console.log('length');
console.log(arr['length']);
console.log(arr.length);
console.log('accediendo por índice');
console.log(arr['1']);
// arr.1 sería un error de sintáxis por eso no es posible
console.log(arr[1]);
console.log('comparando')
console.log(arr[1] === arr['1']);
//es transformado en arr[1] !== arr['01']
console.log(arr[01] !== arr['01']);
console.log('invocando');
// equivalente a arr.toString()
console.log(arr['toString']())
```

Comment: Gracias! o sea.. si yo tengo el sig objeto `var persona = {
    nombre : "juan",
    apellido : "perez",
    nombreCompleto: function() {return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;}
}` "nombreCompleto" sería tanto una propiedad como un método?

Comment: @agujex Exacto!!! y en tu ejemplo estas usando una funcion anónima asignada a la propiedad `nombreCompleto` del objeto persona por lo que para invocarla necesitas hacerlo siempre como una propiedad este. Lee la edición de mi respuesta para que veas como se comporta `this` dependiendo de como se invoca el método. Recuerda que en javascript es válido hacer `var persona = {..., nombreCompleto: function otroNombreCualquiera() { return ....; }}` y funciona idéntico. Para resumir `nombreCompleto` pertenece al objeto, no al método como tal.

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta a tu pregunta: Las propiedades solo almacenan datos, en cambio los métodos realizan acciones y modifican propiedades.

Esto gráficamente es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el objetos persona puede tener N propiedades y M métodos.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

### Programación orientada a objetos

En el ámbito de programación orientada a objetos se habla de propiedades y métodos entre otras cosas. Cuando nos referimos a propiedades significa que un objeto puede tener características, para tu caso el objeto `String`, tiene una característica que es mostrar la longitud de una cadena llamando a la propiedad `length`. Mientras que los métodos proporcionan acciones que el objeto puede realizar, para el objeto `String`, una acción sería crear un formato de una cadena en solo minúsculas lo cual se puede hacer llamando al método `toLowerCase()`. Eso es básicamente una descripción corta de `propiedades` y `métodos`. Un ejemplo sería.

```
str_object = new String("FOO") // crea un obejto tipo string
str_object.length     // devuelve la longitud de la cadena
str_object.toLowerCase()  // convierte a minúsculas la cadena
```

basicamente eso sería un ejemplo del uso de `propiedades` y `métodos`, recuerda que si tu creas tus propios `objetos` puedes también crear tus propias `propiedades` y `métodos`, para llamarlos luego de crear el `objeto`, usas la notación **`.`** como en el ejemplo del string.